# how to delete duplicate item and count total amount of each item in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file looks like this.

| ID  |Value |

| 1   | 20   |

| 2   | 46   |

| 2   | 15   |

| 1   | 45   |

| 3   | 33   |

| 4   | 65   |

| 1   | 12   |

| 5   | 13   |

| 4   | 15   |

i want to simplify it by summarize the total value of each ID and makes it look like this.

| ID number |Total Value |

| 1         | 77         |

| 2         | 61         |

| 3         | 15         |

| 4         | 80         |

| 5         | 13         |

and here is my coding:

```
if ((id_number[i] == id_number[i+1])):
                with open('./ID total value.csv', 'a') as f:
                     total_value = id_data[i] + id_data[i+1]
                     total_value = total_value.tolist()
                 
                     writer_object = writer(f)
                     writer_object.writerow(total_value)
                     f.close()
           
            else:
                with open('./ID total value.csv', 'a') as f:
                     total_value = id_data[i]
                     total_value = total_value.tolist()
                 
                     writer_object = writer(f)
                     writer_object.writerow(total_value)
                     f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to sum the `"ID"` using [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), then rename the columns and finally save the dataframe to csv

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./ID total value.csv')

df = (df.groupby("ID").sum().reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"ID": "ID Number", "Value": "Total Value"}))

print(df)
df.to_csv("./summarized_data.csv", index=False)
```

---

```
   ID Number  Total Value
0          1           77
1          2           61
2          3           33
3          4           80
4          5           13
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial and can easily be dealt with using a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.csv', 'r+') as csv:
    next(csv) # skip column headers
    data = defaultdict(int)
    for line in csv:
        _, key, value, *_ = line.split('|')
        data[key.strip()] += int(value)
        
    csv.seek(0)
    print('|ID Number|Value|', file=csv)

    for k, v in data.items():
        print(f'|{k}|{v}|', file=csv)
    
    csv.truncate()
```